# How to print out the documents in each clusters generated by LDA?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lda, topic-modeling, lsa

The **print_top_words** method from the code below only prints the distribution of the words for each topic:

- **Cluster 1:** word1 , word2 , ....
- **Cluster 2:** word3 , word2 , ....

So, instead of printing out the words distribution, I would like to print the documents in each cluster:

- **Cluster 1:** documents1 , documents2, ....
- **Cluster 2:** documents5 , documents6, ....

**Code:**

```
n_samples = 2000
n_features = 1000
n_topics = 10
n_top_words = 20
def print_top_words(model, feature_names, n_top_words):
    for topic_idx, topic in enumerate(model.components_):
        print("Topic #%d:" % topic_idx)
        print(" ".join([feature_names[i]
                        for i in topic.argsort()[:-n_top_words - 1:-1]]))
    print()


print("Loading dataset...")
t0 = time()
dataset = fetch_20newsgroups(shuffle=True, random_state=1,
                             remove=('headers', 'footers', 'quotes'))
data_samples = dataset.data[:n_samples]
print("done in %0.3fs." % (time() - t0))

# Use tf (raw term count) features for LDA.
print("Extracting tf features for LDA...")
tf_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_df=0.95, min_df=2,
                                max_features=n_features,
                                stop_words='english')
t0 = time()
tf = tf_vectorizer.fit_transform(data_samples)
print("done in %0.3fs." % (time() - t0))



print("Fitting LDA models with tf features, "
      "n_samples=%d and n_features=%d..."
      % (n_samples, n_features))
lda = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_topics=n_topics, max_iter=5,
                                learning_method='online',
                                learning_offset=50.,
                                random_state=0)
t0 = time()
lda.fit(tf)
print("done in %0.3fs." % (time() - t0))

print("\nTopics in LDA model:")
tf_feature_names = tf_vectorizer.get_feature_names()
print_top_words(lda, tf_feature_names, n_top_words)
```